# How to change Nifi variable registry using rest-api

Tags: apache-nifi

I know it's possible to use the rest-api to retrieve the values in the variable registry, but is there a way to set the variable values? When I change a variable I see that the following POST gets sent:

```
http://localhost:8080/nifi-api/process-groups/{ID}/variable-registry/update-requests
```

but I don't really understand where the VariableRegistryEntity comes into play or how I might go about manipulating the variables.

More broadly, what I'm trying to do is manipulate variables inside a custom Nifi processor from another program, so any guidance or ideas on how to do that would be welcome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All the **variables(key,values)** are stored in **variable registry** and when we are updating/creating the variables then we are going to have update-requests rest api call in the back end.

If you are building custom processor to use `the variables` then you need to `create processor` to **enable expression language** then you can refer the variables by using `nifi expression language ${variable_name}` will replace with the `variable_value at run time`.

Refer to [this](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NIFI/Variable+Registry) link for more details regards to variable registry in NiFi

> If you need to **update/create any variable** in the Nifi you can use
>   below rest api call:

```
bash$ curl -i -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST -d '{\
    "processGroupRevision": {\
        "clientId": "<ClientId>",\
        "version": 0\
    },\
    "variableRegistry": {\
        "processGroupId": "<process-group-id>",\
        "variables": [{\
            "variable": {\
                "name": "<variable-name>",\
                "value": "<variable-value>"\
            }\
        }]\
    }\
}' <URL>/nifi-api/process-groups/<process-group-id>/variable-registry/update-requests
```

**This curl call will update the value**

- if variable is already defined and the value got changed and stop and starts all the effected **controller services and processor**.
  [image]
- If the variable is not defined yet then creates new variable with the defined value.

> **How to get ClientID?**

you can make the below Get Rest api call:

```
curl -X GET <URL>/nifi-api/process-groups/<process-group-id>/variable-registry
```

from the response you can get the clientID details.

Comment: Also wanted to mention that the NiFi CLI has a set-var command that can help automate the REST API calls mentioned here

Comment: So does NiPyApi; there are several automation options available for these tasks

Comment: Awesome thank you, this is exactly what I needed. For some reason I had to remove the: "disconnectedNodeAcknowledged" part, but other than that it worked.

Answer (score 2):

To update a variable using nifi-api with kerberos authentification you need to get a token from nifi-api and get the version number then curl the api to update the variable

1. **Get a token**

```
kinit  
token=$(curl -k -X POST --negotiate -u : https://nifi_hostname:port/nifi-api/access/kerberos)
```

2. **Get the version number**

```
curl -k -X GET https://nifi_hostname:port/nifi-api/process-groups/PG-Id/variable-registry -H "Authorization: Bearer $token"
```

3. **Update the variable "web_site"**

```
curl -k -X PUT https://nifi_hostname:port/nifi-api/process-groups/PG-ID/variable-registry  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"processGroupRevision":{"version":version_number},"variableRegistry":{"processGroupId":"PG-ID","variables":[{"variable":{"name":"web_site","value":"stackoverflow"}}]}}' -H "Authorization: Bearer $token"
```

*PG-ID is the process-group Id*